# How to prevent a code from being executed in onResume when application starts?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a piece of code in `onResume` method which I want it to be executed only when the Activity returns from another activity which is started from this activity. Is there a flag or parameter that I can use to find out if activity is newly started or returned from another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) callback. It's being called if user finishes the activity which you have started by using [startActivityForResult(Intent, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Comment: But I have to start all activities with startActivityForResult?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will not get the callback

Comment: [Here's basic guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). You also may need to set result code from started activity (`setResult(RESULT_OK)`) before you call `finish()` on it

Comment: Seems like the only choice. Thank you.

Comment: waiting for 10 minutes, sorry=)